# Android Debug Bridge connect does not work on Ubuntu x64 with androidx86

Tags: android, ubuntu, 64-bit, virtual-machine, adb

I did setup eclipse with ADT and the Android SDK 2.3.3 however it seems that trying to run `./adb connect <ip_of_vm>` does not do anything as the execution hangs and nothing happens. I was able to install the SDK with the `ia32-libs` and eclipse works like a charm... however this is the last step preventing me from attaching my VM to eclipse/adb.

Can anyone explain me how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This is my development framework:

- Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64
- Java 1.6.0_26-b03 (64 bit)
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers: 1.2.2.20100216-1730 (64 bit)
- Android Development Tools: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398
- Android Debug Bridge version: 1.0.29

I do not remember having done anything related to ia32

Do you have 64 bit versions of Java and Eclipse?
I would suggest to uninstall the SDK and install it again without using the ia32-libs

Answer (score 0):

Yes,adb tool is not available with android x86 so you can not use adb commands here some commands are modified also see what all you can use press <kbd>Alt + F1</kbd>  then go at `/system/bin/` then make use of `ls`